# Save the current active tab in redux state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have an app, that has on some routes a controlled tab-bar component. That means I have to hand in the current tab via props and react to the changes of the selected tab by saving the newly selected tab in state.

I am using redux, so I have a central store for state.

Since I have different routes that can contain different tab-bars with different `id`'ed tabs I am not sure what I should save in the state. If I only save the `id` of the tab in state there could be collisions when on 2 different routes tabs have the same `id`. So I'd have to make sure the tab `id`'s are unique across routes.

Since redux works with actions to change state, a `<Link to/>` to another router would also have to set the tab I want to have active on the new route. How would that be accomplished?

Answer (score 0):

This seems like something that should be managed with `react-router`.

```
<Link to="somePage" hash="tab3" />
```

where the router handler for the `somePage` route is:

```
class SomePage extends React.Component {
  render () {
    return (
      <div>
        <TabComponent activeTab={ this.props.location.hash } />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```